# Ionic2 - Get clicked item from ion-list and bind to input field

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an array
`public items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];`
I use this in the view as:

```
<ion-slide> <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="getItem(title)">
      {{ title }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list> </ion-slide>
```

My getItem(title) function is as:

```
getItem(item) {
console.log(item);
this.slider.slideNext();
}
```

So basically I am sliding to next slide item, and pass the item as param.
On my second slide i use:

```
<ion-slide> <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked>Label</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text">{{ item }}</ion-input>
</ion-item> </ion-slide>
```

I want to show the clicked item from the first slide, as a value of the input field in my second slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component just declare a variable to store the selected item, and display that variable in the slide

```
export class MyComponent {

 public selectedItem: any;

 constructor(){}

 getItem(item) {
  // store item in variable
  this.selectedItem = item;
  console.log(item);
  this.slider.slideNext();
 }


}
```

Then in your HTML

```
<ion-slide> 
  <ion-item>
   <ion-label stacked>Label</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"></ion-input>
  </ion-item> 
</ion-slide>
```

Comment: Thanks. It was still showing me an empty input. What worked for me, was using [(ngModel)]="selectedItem". Don't know why, i tried before too but just  passing {{ selectedItem }} does not bind.

Comment: Apologies, it's because it's an input field! Will edit just in case anyone views!